# Issue attempting to run C# application from powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to make a PowerShell script that can run another of my C# applications.
Every time I run the script it causes an error "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods".

PowerShell script:

```
$csprojFile = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csproj -Recurse | Select-Object -First 1
$csprojFile = [Xml](Get-Content $csprojFile.Name)
$addedRefrs = $csprojFile.Project.ItemGroup.Reference

for($i = 0; $i -lt $addedRefrs.Length; $i++){
    $sortItem = $addedRefrs[$i]
    if($sortItem.HintPath -ne $null) {
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($sortItem.HintPath) | out-null
    } elseif($sortItem.Length -gt 2) {
        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName($sortItem) | out-null
    }
}

Add-Type -TypeDefinition "./MainWindow.xaml.cs"
```

Overview of C# file [MainWindow.xaml.cs]:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

namespace Program
{
    class variables
    {
        //A bunch of variables
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void rty_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            //Do something
        }

        async private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do something
        }

        private void xyz_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do something
        }

        private void xyz_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do something
        }

        private void abc_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to change the entry point?
Do I need to change the way assemblies are accessed?
Or am I missing something else entirely?

Comment: You need the contents of the file, not the files relative path.

Comment: Do I also need to reference the other files included in the application or should just the main window file be fine?

Comment: It's not clear why you're trying to load a C# application _via its source-code project_ - if you have a complete project, compile it, and then invoke the executable from PowerShell.

Comment: Good point re `-TypeDefinition`, @Abraham; interestingly, `Add-Type -LiteralPath some.cs` does work (had never tried it before).

Comment: @mklement0, was going to suggest either that, or `-Path` but am not familiar with it enough to do so.

Comment: @mklement0 I'm trying to run it through PowerShell to bypass some security restrictions.

Comment: Leaving aside whether bypassing security restrictions is the right thing to do, I doubt that you'll be able to get a project with presumably multiple source code files to ad-hoc compile this way, except perhaps in simple cases. The C# source code you posted  doesn't explain the error message you got.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure it will end up working. Either way, thanks for the help!